# No TextViews Created

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, csv, textview

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
double MOA;
TextView turretClicks;
boolean noMOA;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    turretClicks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.turretClicks);



    // Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
    View.OnClickListener btnClickCalc = new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double clicks = (MOA * 4);
            String toText = Double.toString(clicks);
            turretClicks.setText(toText);



            EditText range = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rangeEntry);
            String stringRange = range.getText().toString();
            int finalRange = Integer.parseInt(stringRange);
            if (finalRange <= 200) {
                MOA = 0;
            }
            if (finalRange > 200 && finalRange <= 225) {
                MOA = .5;
            }
            if (finalRange > 225 && finalRange <= 250) {
                MOA = 1;
            }
            if (finalRange > 250 && finalRange <= 275) {
                MOA = 1.65;
            }
            if (finalRange > 275 && finalRange <= 300) {
                MOA = 2.25;
            }
            if (finalRange > 300 && finalRange <= 325) {
                MOA = 2.8;
            }
            if (finalRange > 325 && finalRange <= 350) {
                MOA = 3.5;
            }
            if (finalRange > 350 && finalRange <= 375) {
                MOA = 4.0;
            }
            if (finalRange > 375 && finalRange <= 400) {
                MOA = 4.75;
            }
            if (finalRange > 400 && finalRange <= 425) {
                MOA = 5.50;
            }
            if (finalRange > 425 && finalRange <= 450) {
                MOA = 6.25;
            }
            if (finalRange > 450 && finalRange <= 475) {
                MOA = 7.0;
            }
            if (finalRange > 475 && finalRange <= 500) {
                MOA = 7.5;
            }
            if (finalRange > 500 && finalRange <= 525) {
                MOA = 8.25;
            }
            if (finalRange > 525 && finalRange <= 550) {
                MOA = 9.0;
            }
            if (finalRange > 550 && finalRange <= 575) {
                MOA = 9.75;
            }
            if (finalRange > 575 && finalRange <= 600) {
                MOA = 10.5;
            }
            if (finalRange > 600 && finalRange <= 625) {
                MOA = 11.5;
            }
            if (finalRange > 625 && finalRange <= 650) {
                MOA = 12.25;
            }
            if (finalRange > 650 && finalRange <= 675) {
                MOA = 13;
            }
            if (finalRange > 675 && finalRange <= 700) {
                MOA = 14;
            }
            if (finalRange > 700) {
                noMOA = true;
            }

        }
    };


    // Capture our button from layout
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClickCalc);
    // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
    button.setOnClickListener(btnClickCalc);



    final View.OnClickListener btnRecordRange = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText range = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rangeEntry);

            final String recordableClicks = turretClicks.toString();
            final String recordableRange = range.toString();

            try {
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("recordings.csv", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
                outputStreamWriter.write("Clicks" + " " + recordableClicks + "," + " " + "@Range" + recordableRange + "\n");
                outputStreamWriter.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "     Clicks @ Range" + "\n" + "Successfully Recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    };

    // Capture our button from layout
    Button recordRange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordRange);
    // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
    recordRange.setOnClickListener(btnRecordRange);
    // Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener



    final View.OnClickListener btnToRecorded = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,RangeRecords.class));

        }

    };

    // Capture our button from layout
    Button showRecords = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnToRecorded);
    // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
    showRecords.setOnClickListener(btnToRecorded);
    // Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener

}
```

}

RangeRecords.java

```
public class RangeRecords extends ListActivity {
public static TextView ListItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_recorded_ranges);
    readFromFile("recordings.csv");
}


    public String readFromFile(String fname) {
    List<String> rangeList = new ArrayList();
    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(fname);

        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            rangeList.add(stringBuilder.toString());
            View linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linLay);
            for (int i = 0; i < rangeList.size(); i++) {
                TextView value = new TextView(this);
                value.setText(i);
                value.setId(i);
                value.setTextSize(20);
                value.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(value);
            }
        }

        inputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ret;
}

}
```

content_recorded_ranges.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/linLay">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run this program on my phone, it works perfectly on the first activity. When I click the button to switch to the second activity, which should be displaying in TextViews the data I've recorded, the screen is just white. I can see the Android bar on the top where I see my service and battery life, etc, but it is even kinda blurred out a bit as if something is laying over the top of it.

The only reason I have the ListView is because the compiler demanded I have it in the code. I don't want/need it, but apparently the compiler thinks I do.

What am I doing wrong here? I want to display the recorded data on the second activity... so, we calculate the clicks on the turret, shoot the rifle, and record that data to a file if it's a good shot, then all we should have to do is come back to the second activity and view the data we've recorded from all our previous shots at varying ranges.

Anyone? Been at this all day.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is the code now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"       
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_recorded_ranges"
tools:context="lol2dubs.stevemoa.recorded_ranges"
android:background="#fefefe">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:id="@+id/linLay">
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

RangeRecords.java

```
public class RangeRecords extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_recorded_ranges);
    readFromFile("recordings.csv");
}


    public String readFromFile(String fname) {
    List<String> rangeList = new ArrayList();
    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(fname);

        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            rangeList.add(stringBuilder.toString());
            View linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linLay);
            for (int i = 0; i < rangeList.size(); i++) {
                TextView value = new TextView(this);
                value.setText(i);
                value.setId(i);
                value.setTextSize(20);
                value.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(value);
            }
        }

        inputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ret;
}

}
```

Same thing is still occurring after removing the extends ListActivity and the ListView from the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ListView is demanded because you are extending ListActivity. Also, the ListView blocks your TextView so you couldn't see it.

However, you should use stick in using ListView since you are displaying multiple textviews with a dynamic number. See [this](http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90) for a tutorial.

If you don't want to use it then change

```
public class RangeRecords extends ListActivity
```

to

```
public class RangeRecords extends AppCompatActivity
```

Remove ListView on your layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/linLay">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Cleaning the project fixed this. So now I get this error on compile:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: So your solution makes sense, but not working. I removed the ListView and changed the activity and the second activity is still solid white and the Android bar still seems as if it is covered by something. Will update new code on top.

Comment: Are you still getting the compile error or you successfully ran it?

Comment: Can you confirm that your rangeList is not empty?

Comment: It successfully runs. It does not crash at any interval. But I continue to only get a white screen when I load the second activity. I've even tried slicing together some changes from the link you gave me to create a list view and it appears to be working, but still white screen. I have not confirmed rangeList is populated. I will try that now.

Comment: ListView --------                 rangeList.add(stringBuilder.toString());
                String[] rangeArray = new String[ rangeList.size() ];
                rangeList.toArray(rangeArray);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rangeArray);

                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: I did a Log.d("Checkup", rangeList.toString()); -- The output on Debug was:

Comment: 11-01 23:19:33.766 3598-3598/lol2dubs.stevemoa D/Checkup: [Clicks android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{1e93bbae V.ED.... ........ 652,1260-788,1391 #7f0d006d app:id/turretClicks}, @Rangeandroid.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{1eaa1d4f VFED..CL .F...... 310,495-1130,588 #7f0d006c app:id/rangeEntry}]

Comment: So it looks like rangeList is definitely not empty, but it also definitely doesn't have what I want in it. Hmmm.

Comment: Done for the day. More work tomorrow. Let me know if you spot why rangeList is filled with that strange data. (I also checked that output via Toast and it returns the same thing onCreate in the second activity, so the output on Debug above is definitely what's being written to rangeList)

Comment: I guess your rangeList is getting 1 element only because you are appending the results to a StringBuilder and adding the final string to rangeList. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Going to rebuild the writer/reader, and try to find a more solid way to display the data. Thanks for your help!